# Should I install support blocking for a wall below or over the subfloor?

Tags: framing, code-compliance, subfloor

I'm building a new partition wall (non-load-bearing) in my attic. The wall runs parallel to the joists. I'm installing blocking across the joist cavity to strengthen it.

Should I install the subfloor first, or can I install the wall and then install the subfloor?

Comment: I like the subfloor first in case I miss the joist when standing up the wall.

Comment: Your subfloor should be capable of carrying a wall. Why isn't it? Walls in modern homes aren't supported by blocking.

Comment: Or are you implying that the subfloor will end at the wall? Please revise to be more clear about your plans.

Comment: Hi @isherwood , yes - checking if the subfloor can end at the wall.